# Choosing the n most dissimilar items based on a similarity matrix

Tags: optimization, similarity

I have a similarity matrix of dimensions k (**example** of a similarity matrix in the picture below), where each entry shows the similarity between a pair of elements.

[image: here]

what are some ways to pick out n elements that are most dissimilar to each other?